# Concatenate result of a SELECT into an EXECUTE

Tags: postgresql, psql

I am trying to recreate a view from a backup of the definition using EXECUTE in an anonymous code block (`DO $$ ... BEGIN... END$$`), but I cannot get it to work. This is approximately what I have so far:

```
EXECUTE 'CREATE VIEW image AS (' || (SELECT definition FROM tmp_view_backup WHERE viewname = 'image') || ')';
```

The table with the backup of the view definitions was made like this

```
CREATE TABLE  tmp_view_backup
AS
(select viewname,definition from pg_views
WHERE schemaname = 'public'
);
```

It seems like it is the select that causes me some problems in creating the string, as the result is not at all what I anticipated:

```
postgres=# select char_length('CREATE VIEW image AS ('  || (SELECT definition FROM tmp_view_backup WHERE viewname = 'image') || ')') as f ;
 f 
---

(1 row)
```

What is this? An empty row? If I drop the select I get a normal answer (like the string length being `23`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make use of PSQL `\gexec` parameter.

```
SELECT format('CREATE VIEW image AS  %s ', definition)
FROM tmp_view_backup 
WHERE viewname = 'image';\gexec
```

Or in a DO block

```
DO $$
BEGIN

EXECUTE format('CREATE VIEW image AS  %s ', definition)
FROM  tmp_view_backup 
WHERE viewname = 'image';
END $$;
```

Comment: @oligofren see edit. The format type `%s` should be used

Comment: The view definition includes the final semicolon. I guess this means I need to remove the last char?  `WHERE (enc_img.encounter_id = patient_id_for_encounter.id)) pid ON (true)); )`
`(1 row)`

`ERROR:  syntax error at or near ";"`
`LINE 20: ...counter_id = patient_id_for_encounter.id)) pid ON (true)); )`

Comment: @oligofren: Or just don't put unnecessary parenthesis around it.

Comment: @oligofren it should work. Note that I have remove the parenthesis from the `create view as %s` statement

Comment: Alternatively, `SELECT format('CREATE VIEW image AS ( %s )', substr(definition,0, length(definition)) )
FROM tmp_view_backup` :-)